# MVC n-level route building

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvcroutehandler

I want to create a productcatalog with N-Level Categories

> e.g.
>
> ```
> /Catalog/Category1/Category2/../SubCategoryN/Product/{ProductActions}/{ID}
>
> And at the same time be able to 
>
> /Catalog/Category1/Category2/../SubCategoryN/{CategoryActions}
> ```

Is that possible and if Yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the default Route class, but you can make your own route class by deriving from RouteBase. You basically end up having to do all the work yourself of parsing the URL, but you can use the source from Route to help you get started.

Comment: I've been working on deriving from RouteBase, but am confused what GetVirualPathData should do.  Maybe post and example?